# find -exec with \; runs but + terminator fails with "missing argument to -exec"

Tags: bash, unix, find

Sometimes the `find` command refuses to execute with the `+` terminator to its `-exec`, but simply changing `+` to `\;` allows the exec to run.

---

Consider, after the following setup:

```
find_args=( -type f -name "*users*" -cmin -60 )
rsync_args=( -avhP -e 'ssh  -i /home/some_user/.ssh/id_rsa -c arcfour' )
dest=some_user@some_host:/some/destination/
```

This works:

```
# runs rsync once per file, thus slower than it should need to be
find . "${find_args[@]}" -exec rsync "${rsync_args[@]}" {} "$dest" \;
```

...but this one fails:

```
# exactly the same, except for + rather than \;
# ...should use the same rsync call for multiple files.
find . "${find_args[@]}" -exec rsync "${rsync_args[@]}" {} "$dest" +
```

...with the error `find: missing argument to '-exec'`.

I'm using GNU findutils 4.4.2, which is documented to support the `+` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `find -exec ... {} +`, the `+` must be **immediately** after the `{}` (and thus the inserted arguments must be in trailing position). Your given command does not meet this requirement.

---

Consider the following workaround:

```
find . -type f -name "*users*" -cmin -60 \
  -exec sh -c 'rsync -avhP -e "ssh -i /home/some_user/.ssh/id_rsa -c arcfour" "$@" some_user@some_host:/some/destination/' _ {} +
```

Because the `sh -c [...]` line is longer than the `rsync` line which it runs, any argument list passed to the former is guaranteed to work for the latter, so expanding `"$@"` will always succeed.

Comment: Charles, I don't think this is a duplicate. In fact, the *question* you've linked to is an answer to *this* question.

Comment: @ghoti, ...the OP in the other question has already isolated *that* `find` doesn't allow `{} ...other stuff... +` and is asking how to work around it. The OP here hasn't gotten there yet -- but still, the limitation they involve is identical, and any answer to one will answer both.

Comment: @ghoti, ...granted, it may not be *obvious* to the person who's thinking in the terms of the current OP that the other question is the same one, but that's why we (as a site) want good duplicates, keep them around, and allow folks to get rep from questions closed as dupe: As guideposts to a single canonical source of knowledge despite a problem potentially being interpreted different ways when viewed from different angles / with different levels of prior knowledge.

Comment: Good point. One thinks of a duplicate marker as a statement that the current question should perhaps be deleted because it's redundant. Different people will have wildly different ways of expressing similar issues. A more flexible definition of "duplicate" could perhaps be promulgated. :)